# Why are some cells being modified even if they don't fulfill a condition?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the following code in my table view controller:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("itemCell") as! ItemTableViewCell
        cell.itemTitle.text = sortedItems[sortedArray[indexPath.section]]![indexPath.row].itemTitle
        cell.itemType.backgroundColor = sortedItems[sortedArray[indexPath.section]]![indexPath.row].itemColor()

        // Darkening cells
        if /*certain condition is met*/ {
            cell.backgroundColor = .redColor() //this colors other cells while scrolling which shouldn't happen
            cell.itemTitle.text = "Hello" //this is applied correctly, but why?

        }
        return cell
    }
```

As you can see in the 'comments', the code which changes the title is applied properly, while coloring the cell doesn't. Why is this? Does it have anything to do with cells being dequeued? How can I avoid this behavior in order to be able to color certain cells?

Comment: Actually cell background color become change but you could not realize because your itemType back ground color over the cell. Change the cell.itemType.backgroundColor when certain condition met then it will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table cells are reused when they move off screen. Therefore you must assume they have "left over" data from another cell. Consequently, you need to reset them to a known state. The easiest way to do this in your case, is to handle the `else` situation.

```
        if /*certain condition is met*/ {
            cell.backgroundColor = .redColor() //this colors other cells while scrolling which shouldn't happen
            cell.itemTitle.text = "Hello" //this is applied correctly, but why?

        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = .whiteColor() // whatever the default color is
            cell.itemTitle.text = ""
        }
```